# Необходимо уменьшить размер объекта для передачи по сети

Tags: c#, websocket, signalr

Подскажите пожалуйста с  помощью каких тулузов я смогу сжать передаваемый объект по сети ?

Создается объект который состоит из 3 полей.(int double double) 20byte
Пробовал урезать размер с помощью изменения типов (int double short) 14 byte. Но это не влияет на время передачи. Использовал для передачи(Proto.Actor, SignalR, Akka) но скорости отличаются на уровне погрешность (+- запущенных приложений и скорости немного прыгают).

На Proto.Actor 8 byte передается столько же сколько и 14byte. (последний тест)

Что могут посоветовать более опытные ?

Comment: Чего-то мне кажется, что передается не один объект, а последовательность. Вы все рассказали о своей проблеме?

Comment: Да верно, передается не один объект. Передаю последовательность объектов. Выполняю тесты такого плана (Обычный pub/sub)

Есть сервер который будет публиковать новую информацию своим подписчикам.
Eсть 2 машины по 50 клиентов, которые в свою очередь подписываются на топки размещенные на сервере.
После того как все подписались. Начинаю рассылать новую информацию.

Тоесть. Сервер публикует на каждый топик 1 сообщение.
Выходит 2пк +  по 50 клиентов = 100 клиентов. Который подписались ну скажем на 100 топиков. выходит 100 * 100 = 10000 (сообщений). 

Возможно что-то не правильно излагаю..

Comment: Основное время и размер при таких объемах данных уходит на тцп хендшейк, хеадеры тцп пакета итд. Так что оптимизировать надо сам принцип. Не отсылать мелкие пакеты, а собирать конвеер из этих данных и посылать на сервер. Вообще все что касается оптимизации сетевых решений начинается с написания временных лаг тестов для сервера и клиента соответственно. И уже на основании их можно/нужно крутить сетевую архитектуру решения.

Comment: А вообще вас с таким варезом забанят файрволом где то по пути, если это будет интрнет сервис :) принцип работы сильно смахивает на ddos sync атаку :)

Comment: @NewView, можете что-то посоветовать по поводу цп хендшейк, хеадеры тцп пакета итд ? Вы имеете ввиду, что нужно использовать такие инструменты как options.SkipNegotiation = true; у SinglaR?

Comment: я о SinglaR к свой глубокой печали только слышал, но подозреваю что это сетевой фраймворк  :) на самом деле архитектура протокола обмена данными не влияет на инструмент с помощью которого вы реализуете свое решение (это в общих чертах). Вам надо, как я писал выше с начало произвести замеры и выявить 'тонкие места' - что больше всего отнимает время. И потом если результат покажется вам неудовлетворительным, начать придумывать разные оптимизации в подозрительно 'долгих'  блоках кода. Все остальное от лукавого.. Но, по практике тормоза создают большой объем мелких пакетов.

Comment: @NewView можете что-то подсказать по поводу конвеера (собирать конвеер из этих данных и посылать на сервер) ? Примеры реализаций

Comment: Пример реализации - любой вид кольцевого буфера например, по достижению количества/размера/итд - отсылать на сервер. По хорошему, эти части разумно писать на чистом `C/C++`

Comment: Спасибо большое. Попробую

Comment: NewView, подскажите пожалуйста. Я правильно понимаю, что использования класса увеличивает саму передаваемую информацию.

MarketPrice marketPrice = new MarketPrice(1,2.5,2.9);//int double double 4+8+8 = 20
            Console.WriteLine(Marshal.ReadInt32(marketPrice.GetType().TypeHandle.Value, 4));//40 byte


Через планировщик выходит тоже самое...

Comment: Зачем там класс? И как он по сети будет передоваться? Сеарилизовнным в xml? сделайте обычную структуру, к ней еще возможно придется применить `pack` данных чтоб выровнять размер `C/C++`, в `C#` дериктивы маршалинга.

Comment: NewView, Спасибо большое